# How to Convert Selenium-Webdriver objects to Watir-Webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I want to use the selenium webdriver Actions in Watir webdriver.Is it possible?
Also is it possible to use java code in watir webdriver.Please help.
I have gone through many forums and got some knowledge from http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/convert-selenium-webdriver-objects-to-watir-webdriver/,regarding the usage of Selenium in watir.Thanks to Justin KO for the post.

Comment: Hi Justin Thanks for your comment,yes is it possible to use ActionBuilder in watir? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the ActionBuilder by directly interacting with the Watir browser's underlying Selenium driver:

```
browser.driver.action
#=> Selenium::WebDriver::ActionBuilder
```

Many of the action methods expect a Selenium element as the parameter. You can locate the elements using Watir and then get the underlying Selenium element. For example:

```
element = browser.div
element.wd
#=> Selenium::WebDriver::Element
```

Putting it all together, you can perform an action like:

```
watir_element = browser.div
browser.driver.action
  .key_down(:shift)
  .click(watir_element.wd)
  .key_up(:shift)
  .perform
```

Comment: Hi Justin i just followed your steps and try to double click using below code.It works fine in chrome browser,but it is not working in firefox browser.
Code used to Double click:
n=browser.iframe(:id,"iframeResult").button(:ondblclick,"myFunction()")
browser.driver.action.double_click(n.wd).perform
Error in Firefox:
irb(main):007:0> browser.driver.action.double_click(n.wd).perform
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.

Comment: from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-4364-mo5o3r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.j
s:9209:3:in `generateErrorForNativeEvents'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-4364-mo5o3r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.j
s:9253:9:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseMoveTo'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-4364-mo5o3r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_

Comment: from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-4364-mo5o3r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.
js:10889:7:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-4364-mo5o3r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.
js:10831:5:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in

Comment: Watir-WebDriver has a method for double-clicking - eg `browser.button.double_click`. If you are getting problems with native events, which the exception is saying, it is usually that your Selenium-WebDriver version does not support your version of Firefox. Selenium-WebDriver 2.41.0, which it looks like you are using, only supports native events upto Firefox 28. Assuming that you are using a newer version of Firefox, you need to update Selenium-WebDriver.

Comment: Thank you for double_click method.It works fine in chrome.
I have updated selenium webdriver to 2.43.0.Noticed the below error.Also tried the double_click method.Noticed the same error message as below.The only difference is from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:150:in `double_click' is 
added in  the last line of below error message.

Comment: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not get node for element - cannot interact. from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2752-e8z97y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.j
s:9918:3:in `generateErrorForNativeEvents'from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2752-e8z97y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.j
s:10037:7:in

Comment: `FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseDoubleClick' from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2752-e8z97y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
js:11612:16:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2752-e8z97y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
js:11617:7:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'

Comment: from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2752-e8z97y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
js:11559:5:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'

Comment: from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remoteh ttp/common.rb:59:in`create_response'from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/

Comment: Comments really are not the format for this type of discussion. Please consider using an actual question (if the question can be formatted to meet StackOverflow guidelines) or using the Watir Google mailing list.